# Slightly complicated HTML table with merged rows

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following table:

| Comm Layer | Implemented By |
| --- | --- |
| Application | Application |
| Transport | OS |
| Internet | OS |
| Link | OS |
| Link | Hardware |

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Comm Layer</th>
      <th>Implemented By</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Application</td>
      <td>Application</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Transport</td>
      <td>OS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Internet</td>
      <td>OS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Link</td>
      <td>OS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Link</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to merge the two cells that say "Link" and the three cells that say "OS". I tried using the `rowspan` attribute in several ways but to no avail. I was able to merge *either* the two "Link" cells *or* the three "OS" cells, but not both.

Comment: Is this something with fixed content? You make it know and you will not need to change it?

Comment: @StefanP That's right.

Comment: This is actually a "design bug" in HTML's `<table>`: you cannot have a `<tr>` where all cells participate with different `rowspan" values: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382002

Comment: Maybe consider making two tables where one table is your column. You can maybe fix size of the table data to be in OS case, 3 time higher than regular <td>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: you cannot have a `<tr>` where all cells participate in a `rowspan=""` because that creates a zero-height row (as there's no row-specific content). I feel this is a design flaw in HTML.

One workaround is to have a zero-width column that always has non-`rowspan=""` cells (which are propped up with `&nbsp;`, but hidden (using `visibility: hidden;`, not `display: none;`):

(My posted code comments out the removed cells with `<!--<td>OS</td>-->` for illustrative purposes, obviously you can remove those in your final version)

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

tr > *:nth-child(1) { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Comm Layer</th>
      <th>Jurisdiction</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Application</td>
      <td>Application</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Transport</td>
      <td rowspan="3">OS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Internet</td>
      <!--<td>OS</td>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Link</td>
      <!--<td>OS</td>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <!--<td>Link</td>-->
      <td>Hardware</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There's probably improvements using more modern CSS techniques to enforce a minimum row height though - I've been using the `&nbsp;` technique since before I stopped using Dreamweaver in 2004.

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that I don't know how to add CSS to Markdown files on GitHub (that's where I want to put this table).

Comment: @RonInbar That depends on your Markdown implementation. It may be impossible because one of the advantages-of, and use-cases for, Markdown is to allow users to enter formatted text but without letting them style it themselves (remember how awful WYSIWYG editors are?).

Comment: It's the Markdown implementation used by GitHub. It doesn't seem to allow even inline CSS. https://github.community/t/github-flavored-markdown-doesnt-render-css-styles-inside-a-html-block/126258

Comment: There's [this trick for getting around this limitation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/css-in-readme-like-wat/blob/main/explanation.md) but I'm not sure I want to overcomplicate things.

Comment: @RonInbar Honestly, I think using `colspan` is a complication anyway. If this is a regular data-table where there is no _semantic_ relationship between rows, then there's nothing wrong with duplicating `<td>` content.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- Try this one -->

<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellspadding=="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Comm Layer</th>
            <th>Jurisdiction</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Application</td>
            <td>Application</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Transport</td>
            <td rowspan="2">OS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Internet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Link</td>
            <td>OS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hardware</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question because the "Link" cell is still manually repeated.

Comment: You still have a repeated "OS" cell.

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: @SadaqatAli There are still two cells that say "OS". I want to have only once such cell, spanning 3 rows.